# Loading a movie strip into cache without using proxies

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have tried searching online, but I cannot find a clear answer...

I want to make a movie strip easier to edit by caching its frames to RAM. I have configured the Sequencer Cache Limit to 8192 MB, which should be more than enough for the <1 GB video.

My question is: Is there an easy way to automatically cache all of a movie strip's frames?

Individual frames get cached when I have the playhead on them. Playing the video from the beginning stutters a lot, so the playhead skips frames and caches very few of them. Is there a better way to cache movie strips?

I know proxies are a thing, but if possible I would rather use my RAM than fill more disk space.

Do you guys know of a Blender feature or custom script that allows for automatic movie strip caching? Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is a wip patch which will cache to disk, but it is not ready to be included in Blender yet: https://developer.blender.org/D5524